# useEffect missing dependencies 'props'

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning redux. I keep running into the warning above. Here are the codes:

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchPosts} from '../actions/postActions'

function Post(props){

   useEffect(
   () => {
      props.fetchPosts();
   },[]);

    const postItems = props.posts.map(post => (
        <div key={post.id}>
            <h3>{post.title}</h3>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
        </div>
    ));
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Post</h1>
            {postItems}
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    posts: state.posts.items
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(Post);
```

fetchPost declaration if you need:

```
export const fetchPosts = () => dispatch => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=10')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(posts => dispatch({
            type: FETCH_POSTS,
            payload: posts
        }));
```

Now I think the problem is because fetchPost is declared as an action in another folder, which creates the error. Reading SO, the best solution would be to move the fetchPosts declaration inside useEffect. Should I do that in redux, because so many tutorials put the actions seperately, rather than doing it in the same folder as the component. Also, it keeps saying I'm missing specificly props, but when I put props into the dependencies array, it creates an infinite loop. So can you guys help me with this, thank you. I can guarantee I have read through all the questions here, but in those cases they are missing the functions, and not props itself, so I think I should ask this. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Please show me full code of your `post` component

Comment: If you add the end of the component, I suspect you will be missing the connect() statement with mapDispatchToProps for that action. e.g `export default connect(null, {fetchPosts})(Post)`

Comment: @Oliver yes it's already included.

Comment: @ShotaTopchishvili I have editted to show all the codes. It's fetching the data alright, but it keeps giving me that warning, some say to ignore that, should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify all the dependencies accessed in `useEffect`'s callback. In this case you just need to add `fetchPosts`:

```
function Post({fetchPosts}){

   useEffect(() => {
     fetchPosts();
   },[fetchPosts]);
```

Note that you don't need to import `fetchPosts` from actions if the function is available on the component's props.

More info in the [official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies).

Comment: if i remove props from function Posts({fetchPosts}), it gives an error that props is not defined when i use props later in props.posts.map. And I try including both of them in function, but it gives more errors for some reasons.

Comment: anything that refers to `props.` will need to be destructured either in the function parentheses or inside the function but Clarity's solution above is correct

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Thank you @Clarity